# Failed to build tensorflow 1.4 by bazel on Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04, bazel

Platform：

- ubuntu 16.04LTS
- TensorFlow 1.4.0
- bazel 0.5.4
- cuda 8.0
- cudnn 6.0

When I build tensorflow in above conditions as https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources, it occurs such errors:

```
ERROR: /home/.cache/bazel/_bazel/978efb9ded2e9e03d9ec3f33c5686099/external/local_config_cuda/cuda/BUILD:196:1: @local_config_cuda//cuda:cuda-include: illegal output file name 'cuda/include/ï¼' in rule @local_config_cuda//cuda:cuda-include: invalid target name 'cuda/include/ï¼': target names may not contain '�'.
ERROR: /home/.cache/bazel/_bazel/978efb9ded2e9e03d9ec3f33c5686099/external/local_config_cuda/cuda/BUILD:196:1: @local_config_cuda//cuda:cuda-include: missing value for mandatory attribute 'outs' in 'genrule' rule.
ERROR: /home/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:1334:1: Target '@local_config_cuda//cuda:using_clang' contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by '//tensorflow/python:gen_random_ops_py_wrappers_cc'.
ERROR: /home/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:1334:1: Target '@local_config_cuda//cuda:using_nvcc' contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by '//tensorflow/python:gen_random_ops_py_wrappers_cc'.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed; build aborted.
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.472s
```

Could anyone solve this?

Comment: maybe try updating bazel.

Comment: The latest Bazel release is [0.13.0](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases). Please try that and report back if it still doesn't work.